# How to make page and widgets plugable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, plugins

We are building a web application where some of the modules will be available only if you buy the ultimate license. If you have the ultimate license then my pages will need to show certain widgets and also the base widgets needs to have the capability to extend such as dropdown buttons to show additional ultimate options. Now I don't want to have if else conditions polluted everywhere. I want to have some kinda plugin architecture that will automatically plug the widgets if the logged in user has the ultimate license. Can anybody please point me to projects or article which solves these issues. Important thing here is that the widgets and items need to plug into the base pages only if you have ultimate

Please note that the project is based on MVC 4 with Razor

Comment: As I understand of your question, you want to restrict your users to access some parts of your application. Am I right?

Comment: you are correct in a way but I want the sections in the views to only render if the user has the licenses. I would not want to use if else everywhere in the code

Comment: As far as I know, Plugin Architecture is a design method for infrastructure of an application. For your scenario I think you should use Role-based mechanism that is more suitable.

Comment: have you got any examples of the role based implementation